Using PHPMailer when already have an access token
I have been Googling for a few days trying to understand whether it is possible to use PHPMailer OAUTH2 without the need for a provider package. I have an access token management process already, so I can always arrive at the moment of sending an email, good to go with a valid, non-expired access token. All the examples of using OAUTH2 that i have found show the creation of a provider, using one of the packages, which is then fed to the mail->setOAuth() parameter. As far as I can tell, the primary function of these is to return an access token .. which I already have, along with all the other bits needed (ID, secret, etc.). I was hoping to find guidance on how to feed my access token in to the process.
I won't be surprised to learn that I am missing something plainly obvious - so if someone could point it out for me, I'd appreciate it.

The "plainly obvious" part is that all of these mechanisms work by providing an implementation of PHPMailer's OAuthTokenProvider interface, which consists of just one method that returns a string containing the base64-encoded token, so the solution here is to make your own class that implements this interface, along the lines of:
namespace my\App;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuthTokenProvider;

class MyTokenProvider implements OAuthTokenProvider
{
    public function getOauth64()
    {
        //Do whatever you have to do to get the token here
        //See the interface code for the expected token format
        return 'my token string';
    }
}

Then pass it to PHPMailer and tell it to use XOAUTH2:
$oauthTokenProvider = new \my\App\MyTokenProvider();
$mail->setOAuth($oauthTokenProvider);
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';


Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry that it has taken so long to respond ... it has been a lengthy road, full of Microsoft potholes ... but today, I have successfully sent an email from my application, via XOAUTH2, using PHPMailer and the code above. OMG! Question, tho ... When you request authorisation, you are not told the email address of the login that consented to your request, yet you have to use it to generate the token string. How do people deal with that?

The user needs to be logged in when they request the token, so it doesn’t have to ask for it explicitly.

True, but we need to add the username to the token, when it comes time to use it.

I think you’d normally get that in the oauth callback, though PHPMailer doesn’t get involved with that.

I have found an email address in the id_token's JWT. I needed to add openid and profile (although possibly not the latter) to the scope to make it appear in the payload. I'm not sure if this will work reliably, as I have read that if the user has more than one email address (alias?), it returns them all. I am surprised about the lack of guidance on this subject on the internet ... maybe a new post ...
